# Is Duryodhana's karma ongoing?

Tags: duryodhana

Is [Duryodhana's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duryodhana) *[karma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma)* done? I really don't know much about this fellow except that he was leader of [Kauravas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaurava).  The reason I ask is because someone insinuated that I was he, the Kaurava, Duryodhana. Maybe they were just trying to say I was a bad person, but really, is his karma persisting?

any true ([Satya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satya)) information is useful.

Comment: Lol, they were just saying you're a deluded/disgusting/vile person. As for Karma, since Duryodhana is Kali avataara, his work is indeed not done. He (or rather, his original form)'s the one ruling/affecting/manipulating the current Kali Yuga.